# Angular 6 @ngrx/store api call

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to add @ngrx/store with api calls in my application.

But I actually didn't find where's the best place to make the api call and where the best place to make the dispatch call is.

For example, I have a Reducer "AllBooks"

**My Component** Books

Gets the data from My **Book Service**

The Book service makes the **api call** and gets the data.

***The API call***

In some tutorials I see that the api call is in the reducer
and in others the api call is in the service.

***The dispatch call***

In some tutorial I see that the dispatch call is made from the component.
and in others the api dispatch is in the service.

I'm looking for a new simple demo code for angular 6 that uses @ngrx/store with api calls to learn what's the best practice to organize the code

This is my current component code(constructor):

```typescript
this._passwordService.getPasswordsById(id).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.password = data;
    this._store.dispatch(new PasswordActions.GetPassword(this.password));

    this.onInit();
  },
  (error: any) => { console.log(error) })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the service in your effects. Effects are from the `@ngrx/effects` package which is the place to handle your side effects. See the [docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects) for more information.

You can find an example in the [NgRx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app).